# JQuery Ajax: assign response to two variables using a single request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm using JQuery Ajax to collect data from a MySQL database.

My PHP script looks like:

```
$categorias= array_map(function($a) { return ($a["categorias"]); }, $rows);
$real = array_map(function($a) { return floatval($a["real"]); }, $rows);
$orcamento = array_map(function($a) { return floatval($a["orcamento"]); }, $rows);

echo json_encode($categorias);

echo json_encode(array(
    array(name => 'Orçamento', data => $orcamento),
    array(name => 'Real', data => $real)
));
```

This is returning two arrays as follows:

```
["Vendas","Services","Other"][{"name":"Oçamento","data":[14000,8500,0]},{"name":"Real","data":[3738,11120.99,15000]}]
```

My question is: in my ajax call, can I assign the first array to a variable and the second to another variable? How?

This means using only one Ajax and server request only.

Currently, I have:

```
    $.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '../myData.php',
            success: function (response) {
                dados = response; 
                (...)
            }
     });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
echo json_encode(array(
'categorias' => $categorias,
'real' =>    array(name => 'Orçamento', data => $orcamento),
'orcamento' =>    array(name => 'Real', data => $real)
));
```

And in JS:

```
$.ajax({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: '../myData.php',
            success: function (response) {
                categorias = response.categorias;
                real = response.real;
                (...)
            }
     });
```

Comment: It makes sense, the issue here is that this will give me 3 objects. However, I only neeed two: the first with categoias and the second with (real and orçamento) as described in my question.

Comment: It was just example, how you cant combine your data in one response.